# Colab ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have been following

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12qC2abKAIAlUM_jNAokGlooKY-idbSxi
pretty exactly but I still cannot access any of my code from other files

**My attempt:**

```
!ls /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/*.ipynb

!cat '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/module_i_want.ipynb'

import sys

sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My Drive')

import module_i_want as mod

mod.loadData()
```

**I am getting:**

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_i_want'

**I have tried:**

```
import os
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('module_i_want.ipynb')))
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('module_im_in.ipynb')))
```

and they both return

/content

I can see both files to the left in my mounted drive (in the same folder) but I can't seem to find any way to import anything

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**
For .ipynb files in Google Colab you need to specifically install

!pip install import_ipynb

and then:

import import_ipynb

in order to deal with this type of file